# How do I do a nested list (array) of schema references in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to build a schema which has a list of items that I want to have an enforced schema.

Basically here is the data I want to validate against the schema:

```
data = {
    "VIN" : "123",
    "timestamp" : "xxxx",
    "model" : "jeep",
    "inspections": [
        { "door_badge" : 
             {
                "expected": "yes",
                "image": "/image/path/here",
                "state": 1
            },
        },
        {
            "rear_badge" :
            {
                "expected" : "yes",
                "image" : "/image/path/here",
                "state": 1
            }


        }
    ],
}
```

And my schema mapping as is such but seem to be getting errors when trying to validate:

```
schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "inspection": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "expected" : { "type": "string" },
                "found": { "type" : "string"},
                "state" : { "enum" : [0,1] },
                "image" : { "type" : "string"}
            },
            "required": ["state", "image"]
        },
        "inspections" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/inspection"
            },
            "required" : ["items"]
        },

    },
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "VIN" : { "type" : "string" },
        "timestamp" : { "type" : "string"},
        "model" : { "type" : "string"},
        "inspections" : { "$ref" : "#/definitions/inspections"}
    },
    "required": ["VIN", "timestamp", "model"]
}
```

I basically want sub list within the inspection list but also to validate based on that type of item.

---

SOLUTION:
Thanks to jruizaranguren's help the solution was:

```
schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "inspection": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "expected" : { "type": "string" },
                "found": { "type" : "string"},
                "state" : { "enum" : [0,1] },
                "image" : { "type" : "string"}
            },
            "required": ["state", "image", "expected"]
        },
    },
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "VIN" : { "type" : "string" },
        "timestamp" : { "type" : "string"},
        "model" : { "type" : "string"},
        "inspections" : { 
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "maxProperties": 1,
                "minProperties": 1,
                "additionalProperties" : {
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/inspection"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["VIN", "timestamp", "model", "inspections"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are constraining each item in the array to be of the form:

```
{
    "expected": "yes",
    "image": "/image/path/here",
    "state": 1
}
```

But your objects are of the form:

```
{ "door_badge" : 
    {
        "expected": "yes",
        "image": "/image/path/here",
         "state": 1
    },
}
```

One way to achieve this would be to use `additionalProperties` in the `items` clause:

```
"items" : 
    { 
            "type" : "object",
            "maxProperties": 1,
            "minProperties": 1,
            "additionalProperties" : {
                "$ref" : "#/definitions/inspection"
            }
    }
```

If you can enforce some rules on these properties keys (for instance, all must end with **badge**) then you may use `patternProperties` clause with a regular expression.

Comment: Actually one follow up question which seems to be weird.  I am trying to set { "expected" :  { "enum" : ["yes","maybe"] }} but getting validation errors, but the enum seems to work for state which has numbers instead of strings.  I referred to the documentation for JSON schema and it looks like my enum definition is correct for strings.

Comment: Please add your sample and schema in a new question and will have a look.

Comment: I think I discovered what happened and appears to be working, I had an extra pair of {} in my enum list, so instead of { "enum": ["a","b"] } I had { "enum": { ["a","b"] } }.  Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar post with a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876240/how-do-i-do-a-nested-list-array-of-schema-references-in-json-schema-that-isnt